# Sensor Manager is not available

Tags: android

can please anyone explain where did i go wrong?

I'm trying to make a step counter  , but everytime I get " Sensor manager is not available "

this is my code 
    `    package com.example.pfe.mymapapplication.ui.activity;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context; 
import android.hardware.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.pfe.mymapapplication.R;
import com.txusballesteros.widgets.FitChart;

public class LocationServiceActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

private SensorManager sensorManager;
boolean activityRunning;
static FitChart fitChart ;
private TextView count;
// app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_service);
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    count = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.count);
    fitChart = (FitChart)findViewById(R.id.fitChart);
    assert fitChart != null;
    fitChart.setMinValue(0f);
    fitChart.setMaxValue(250f);
    fitChart.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            return false;
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    activityRunning = true;
    Sensor countSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
    if (countSensor != null) {
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, countSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sensor Manager is not available!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    activityRunning = true;
    // if you unregister the last listener, the hardware will stop detecting step events
 //        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (activityRunning) {
        fitChart.setValue(event.values[0]);
        count.setText(""+ (int)event.values[0]+"M");
        Log.e("Distance" , ""+ event.values[0]);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
}
}`
```

please help me  !! please take a note that I have this error in import android.annotation.SystemApi; it wouldn't resolve SystemApi

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your device does not have a step counter sensor, apparently.

Comment: no actually i downloaded a step counter app and it worked just fine, again i'm saying that i may have a problem with annotation.SystemApi since it doesn't resolve SystemApi

Comment: @NefissaKhedher: "i downloaded a step counter app and it worked just fine" -- that will not help you with your "Sensor manager is not available" problem, which is because your device does not have a step counter sensor, if the code in your question is accurate. "since it doesn't resolve SystemApi" -- your code does not refer to that symbol. Perhaps your question does not have code that is causing your problems.